# How could Deku hit 1000,000% One for All punch when he had no memory of it?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In his fight against Bloodthirsty Muscular, Deku hits a 1000,000% One for All punch when we haven’t seen even All Might use that much power. How can this be possible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46793/does-one-for-all-give-unlimited-power/46804#46804

Comment: it just felt like that to him so he said it. otherwise if a 100% could destroy his hand a1000,000% would make him explode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was confirmed by the Author that it wasn't actually 1000,000%. Deku said that to pump himself up.

This is explained in [this article](https://comicbook.com/anime/2018/04/29/my-hero-academia-delaware-detroit-smash-izuku-anime-creator-comments/), as well as the image below:

[image: "The Supplementary Info - 1,000,000 percent?"]

Comment: To be exact and clarify, the author confirmed this in volume 9, in a page explaining that the "1,000,000%" Smash was indeed just a battle cry fueled by adrenaline.

Answer (score 1):

In the last episode of My Hero Academia (Season 3, episode 8) , they gave an explanation for this (spoilers)

> According to the doctor who cured Midoriya from his battle with muscular, when Midoriya says "100%" he would be using 80% of his power that's the upper limit a person can use in normal situations, and when Midoriya says 1,000,000%, he was using 100% of his power which is a power only a person can use when he is in an extreme situation, something that makes any person (including Midoriya) being bad injured after because no person is capable of using 100% of his power without hurting itself, that's why a person can only use 80% of his power in normal situations for not hurting his own body [image][image]